Find Integral Over Upper Half Unit Circle
I want to calculate the following integral
$$
\int_{C^{+}} \frac{dz}{z-a}
,$$
where $|a| < 1$ and $C^{+}$ denotes the set $\{ (x,y): x^2+y^2=1 , \, y\geq0\}$.
As far as I know, the Residue Theorem can be applied to closed curves, further $log(z-a)$ can not be a primitive even by considering the branch as $(\frac{-\pi}{2}<arg<\frac{3\pi}{2})$ because it is not holomorphic at $z=a$ unless $a$ is purely imaginary.
Thank you for your time.

You need an orientation for the path $C^+$, I take this to be counterclockwise starting at $1$ ending at $-1$.
The singularity of $\log(z-a)$ doesn't occur on the path $C^+$, so you can just use the FTC and it is $\log(1-a)-\log(-1-a)$. However, we need a logarithm with a branch cut that doesn't cut into $C^+$ as well. This will work if we take the branch cut to occur on the line $x=\Re (a)$, $y\le \Im(a)$. Then the logarithm of $re^{i\theta}$ is $\log(r)+i\theta$ as long as we take $-\pi/2\le\theta\lt 3\pi/2$.
For example, with $a=\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$, one has $1-a=1-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-\pi i/6}$ and $-1-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}e^{7\pi i/6}$ giving
$$\int_{C^+}\frac{1}{z-a}\,dz=\frac{7\pi i}{6}-\frac{-\pi i}{6}=\frac{4\pi i}{3}$$

I think the answer should be $log(-1-a) - log(1-a)$.

Yes, you are right, I had the orientation wrong.
